# Perush Hamishna of Rambam Online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, rambam

Where can I find Maimonides' commentary to the Mishna in a Hebrew translation online (for free) as text?

Comment: meaning, copy-and-paste-able?

Comment: @yEz yeah. [15]

Comment: he.wikitext has 3 or 4 masechtos.  I remember searching around and not finding much else.  (Moridoweedhyaa7qob emailed me pdfs of the קאפח translation but that won't help you much)

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D is the _Vikitekst_ (Wikisource) one @yEz refers to, I think. Very sparse coverage.

Comment: @yEz the next best thing after text is pdf. Where could I access the Qafih pdfs?

Comment: If you're willing to settle for a non-Qafih translation, the _Mishnayot Zekher Chanokh_ at HebrewBooks (search for "משניות זכר חנוך" there) have the classical translation, and seem to be OCR'd, so you should be able to copy-and-paste from them in a PDF reader (though I haven't tried it myself). At least you'll have a more readable format.

Comment: @yEz you spelled my named wrong. im truly hurt. also i have issues with a ton of people getting those pdfs. i dont want it to be a big public thing

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob understood.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob I did my best, but I don't speak your language :)

Comment: More specific: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73044

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm years late on this one, but [right here](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Mishnah/Commentary/Rambam)